# Undefined symbol while using Keil IDE

Tags: c, linker-errors, keil, nrf51

I am using Nordic nRF51-DK SDK_11 and the soft device s130.

I encountered the following error while adding device manager. I'm using Keil compiler.

> ._build\nrf51422_xxac_s130.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol
>   dm_init (referred from main.o). ._build\nrf51422_xxac_s130.axf: Error:
>   L6218E: Undefined symbol dm_register (referred from main.o). Not
>   enough information to list image symbols.

I have included device_manager.h in the PATHS. Using Keil, I did it by going to Menu->Flash->Configure Flash Tools ... -> Include Paths -> Add components\ble\device_manager

What else did I miss out?

Comment: The header that you seem to have included and made its path known to the compiler is normally only *declaring* a function. It needs to be *defined* somewhere (the "real code") - That would normally be in an object file or library that **you need to link** your code with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the SDK version you want to use you need to compile and link `device_manager_peripheral.c`. For NRF5 SDK version 11.0.0 it resides in the folder `<path to sdk>/nRF5_SDK_11/components/ble/device_manager`.

You can find a tutorial [here](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/tutorials/15/).